# PHP stops working in a loop of binary string after 0x03 End of Text

Tags: php

I'm reading a binary file and trying to echo its content escaping all control characters:

```
$size    = filesize($filename);
$handle  = fopen($filename, "rb");
$content = utf8_encode_escape(fread($handle, $bytes));

function utf8_encode_escape ($string) {

    $encoded = str_split(utf8_encode($string));
    $escaped = "";

    foreach ($encoded as $char) {
        $code = ord($char);
        echo $code . " ";

        if ($code <= 32) {
            $escaped .= unichr(9216 + $code);
        }
        else if ($code == 127) {
            $escaped .= unichr(9249);
        }
        else {
            $escaped .= chr($code);
        }
    }

    return $escaped;
}

function unichr($u) {
    return mb_convert_encoding('&#' . intval($u) . ';', 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
}
```

`$content` is supposed to be a string with all control characters replaced by Unicode Symbol For (e.g Symbol for End of Transmission: ␄), however the loop and the script stops without error after the `0x00` byte. The file I'm reading is conhost.exe:

[image]

The `echo $code . " ";` displays the following sequence: `77 90 144 0`, means that the script stops at the `0x03` byte -- End of Text. Is there any reason behind this, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I forgot to include the `mb_string` extension. Case closed.